# Image filter - Convolution

Tags: java, image-processing, marvin-framework

I am trying to implement image filter ( using convulution). I've spent all day trying to figure out what's going on and I cannot find a mistake. The filter works only when I use it to blur the image. In other cases it doesn't work properly: For example this is the original picture(before filtering):

[image: The picture before filtering]

And this is the picture after filtering with this matrix:

[image]

[image: picture after embossing filter]

I use [Marvin Image Processing Framework](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/) and [jblas library](http://mikiobraun.github.io/jblas/) in my code:

```
  public class FiltrySploty extends MarvinAbstractImagePlugin {
@Override
public void load() {
}

@Override
public MarvinAttributesPanel getAttributesPanel() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void process(
        MarvinImage imageIn,
        MarvinImage imageOut,
        MarvinAttributes attributesOut,
        MarvinImageMask mask,
        boolean previewMode) {

    double norm=0;

    DoubleMatrix filter = (DoubleMatrix)getAttribute("filter");

    for ( int i = 0; i < filter.getRows();i++)
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < filter.getColumns();j++)
        {
            norm=norm+filter.get(i, j); 

        }
    }

    int marginx = ((filter.getRows()-1)/2);
    int marginy = ((filter.getColumns()-1)/2);


    for (int x = marginx; x < imageIn.getWidth()-marginx; x++) {
        for (int y = marginy; y < imageIn.getHeight()-marginy; y++) {                
            double SumRed=0;
            double SumGreen=0;
            double SumBlue=0;
            for ( int i = x-marginx,k=0 ; k < filter.getRows();i++,k++)
            {
                for ( int j = y-marginy, l=0 ; l <filter.getColumns();j++,l++)
                {
                    SumRed= SumRed+(filter.get(k, l)*imageIn.getIntComponent0(i, j)); 
                    SumGreen= SumGreen+(filter.get(k, l)*imageIn.getIntComponent1(i, j));
                    SumBlue= SumBlue+(filter.get(k, l)*imageIn.getIntComponent2(i, j));  
                }
            }
            SumRed = SumRed/norm;
            SumGreen = SumGreen/norm;
            SumBlue = SumBlue/norm; // normalization

            if(SumRed>255.0) SumRed=255.0;
            else if(SumRed<0.0) SumRed=0.0;
            if(SumGreen>255.0) SumGreen=255.0;
            else if(SumGreen<0.0) SumGreen=0.0;
            if(SumBlue>255.0) SumBlue=255.0;
            else if(SumBlue<0.0) SumBlue=0.0;

            imageOut.setIntColor(x, y, (int)(SumRed), (int)(SumGreen), (int)(SumBlue));


        }
    }
}
```

}

Seeing the effect of filtering I suppose that the SumRed, SumGreen and SumBlue are out of range and they are setting to 255 or 0 values. But I have no idea why.

Comment: You should check the value of `norm`...

Comment: I've already done it, and it seems ok. norm for this matrix is -1.0.

Comment: Why aren't you using ConvolveOp ? Java 2D supports this out of the box

Comment: Ok, and what is the effect of dividing by -1?

Comment: If the sum was a positive number, I'm getting the negative number hence the value is setting to 0.0. That's right. But I have no idea how to make normalization then. how it should be done?.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "normalisation" - what do you want to normalise?

Comment: I thought that the process of convolving the image, is something like making the weighted arithmetic mean of the surrounding pixels with the weights defined in a kernel matrix ( different for each kind of filter). So that's the reason why I've tried to divide by the sum of matrix elements.

Comment: That's right in general. (You could also consider doing this normalization in you kernel - that is, you could divide the elements of your kernel by the sum of all kernel elements). It's hard (for me) to foresee the effect that such a kernel will have, but this one looks odd. Are you sure that the input image and the output image and **not** the same instance? (They **have** to be different instances!). Some debugging output might help as well, like `System.out.println("Computed sums "+sumRed+" "+sumGreen+" "+sumBlue+", now dividing by "+norm)` etc...